# Regular expressions in translate filter external dictionary

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Below is example of my yml dictionary:

```
'Rejected': onewordstatus
'^Send to some module': twoword status
'^Image converted': twoword status
'Something': two wordstatus 
'Error - input Source = 'F' or 'E'': status2 <== single quotes are part of regex
'^[a-z;A-Z]* Module Done$': status3
```

How do I store regular expressions in yml?

I'm just starting to extract those mappings to external files so I can choose `csv` or `json` if these are better to store regexes.